# How to change notification mail ->action function button default color Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, email, notifications

I have a task. And in Notifications mail file I need to add a button in **public function toMail():**

I have done it, but by default, the background color of the button is **black**, and I need to make it **blue**. How do I change the color in this function and code of the button?

Here is the code exampple:

```
public function toMail(): MailMessage
{
return (new MailMessage())
->action('Button name', rout('route.name'))
}
```

SO how to change the button color that the background color change from default black to my choosing (for example blue)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SimpleMessage class is designed for creating simple messages that have one call to action button, you can find the code that powers the functionality in [Illuminate/Notifications/Messages/SimpleMessage.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Notifications/Messages/SimpleMessage.php#L191) and the template for the SimpleMessage emails can be found in [Illuminate/Notifications/resources/views/email.blade.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Notifications/resources/views/email.blade.php) — note the single button.

You can create more complex messages using the Markdown Mail Notifications feature, which will allow you to include as many buttons as you like. You can implement this like so:

Run the command to generate a new notification and pass in the markdown option, e.g: php artisan make:notification InvoicePaid --markdown=mail.invoice.paid
Open the newly created template, e.g: views/mail/invoice/paid.blade.php
Add as many buttons as you like, e.g:

```
@component('mail::message')
  # Introduction

  @component('mail::button', ['url' => $url1])
  Button 1 Text
  @endcomponent

  @component('mail::button', ['url' => $url2])
  Button 2 Text
  @endcomponent

  @component('mail::button', ['url' => $url3])
  Button 3 Text
  @endcomponent
```

Thanks,
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
Replace your calls to SimpleMessage methods with a reference to your markdown template when constructing your email, e.g:

```
return (new MailMessage)
  ->subject($this->options['subject'])
  ->markdown('mail.invoice.paid', $this->options);
```

The second parameter in the markdown method is an array to pass into your view, through this you can include the various values you'd like to include in your email, such as contentParagraph1, greeting and salutation.

Comment: But what if I need to adjust just this notification file I already have and don't need or can't create anything new (any new file to implement Markdown)? Is there no way to change the button color directly in this code? For example like typing something like ->line(new HtmlString(->action('buttonName', route('route.name')) <class="btn btn" color="blue");